# Слетел перевод с предложением поделиться вопросом

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, sharing

Слетел перевод в форме ответа:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня там вообще текст "Знаете кого-то, кто может ответить? Share a link to this question via email, , or . ".

Comment: А `ru.traducir.win` тем временем прилёг.

Comment: Слетевший перевод - это, кстати, следствие выпиливания Google+ из-за его смерти. Надо бы вконтактик добавить на его место с товарищем майором :) Или, может быть, инстаграм для любителей кода картинками.

Comment: @Suvitruf ссылки порезались AdBlock'ом? У меня традусёр тоже теперь через VPN только работает. Правда я с рабочего интернета, а не с домашнего.

Comment: @älёxölüt лол, да. Adblock резал оказывается :D

Comment: @älёxölüt traducir.win у меня тоже теперь только через vpn. Хотя вчера работал.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev возможно, стоит передать привет РКН :)

Comment: @älёxölüt вы правы. Теперь вместо ошибки: "Уважаемые пользователи! Приносим свои извинения, доступ к информационному ресурсу ограничен на основании Федерального закона от 27 июля 2006 г. № 149-ФЗ «Об информации, информационных технологиях и защите информации»" Прелестно)

Comment: Что за провайдер? Возможно, есть смысл оформить баг репорт здесь на Мете об этом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Добавил перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/string/11171):

> Поделитесь ссылкой на этот вопрос по почте, через Твиттер или Facebook.

Появится после подкачки и пересборки. Как обычно.

Comment: Почему "Твиттер" по русски? Я бы написал "... по email, Twitter или Facebook."

Comment: @АндрейNOP Twitter своё название переводит в отличии от Facebook, поэтому по-русски. "По Twitter" это вообще очень странно звучит.